# Setting dynamic height of scrolling panel?

Tags: xpages

I have a view withing a panel with this styleCLass applied.

.scrollPanel { width:100%; height: 375px; overflow: auto;}

That panel is nested with an extension pages Application control.

I want both the height and the width of the panel set so the scroll bars of the panel appear and the browsers scroll bars are NOT activated.

This CSS works perfectly for width.  I can resize my browser window and the width of the panel adjusts as needed and the browser horizontal scroll bars never come on.

But if I try 100% for height, it does not work the same.   If I resize for height then the vertical scroll bars for the browser appear.

Also it would be nice to have the height of the panel always equal to the height of the available screen.   With 100%, the height is very small if the view is collapsed.  The height expands when the view expands.  I would like for it always to be the same size percentage wise to the available height of the browser.

P.S. The set size I have of 375 works perfectly with the exception it does not resize with the browser.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try min-height instead of height.

Comment: That did not work.  Panel will stay that height and causes browser scroll bars to show up when the browser is made smaller.

Comment: so you want scroll bars inside of the div that holds the view? "overflow: scroll" should make scroll bars appear if the content is larger than the div itself. Then it's a question of finding the correct height for the div.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem.  Finding the correct height of the div.  I think it would need to be dynamic and done in JS but not sure and for sure would not know how to do it.

Comment: Can you add the source code for a simple XPage demo to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register a window.onresize event that fetches the actual size of the window and modifies the panel accordingly, e.g. by setting its height with a style.

So the best way would be to create a method that modifies the size of your panel according to the windows size, respecting a minimum and a maximum value. Once that function is finished, you would just need to register it to the onresize event that gets fired when anything has changed the viewports display dimensions (read, a real resize or something that has enabled the windows scrollbars).

In the perfect world you would debounce/throttle the execution of this method to maybe at most every 100ms to avoid excessive CPU load during a window resize with the mouse and a window border, because depending on the browser, that event gets fired on every single pixel the mouse has moved during such a resize - which is fairly often and may lead to a slower UI response.